# Finding whether a sentence is positive, neutral or negative?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I want to create a script that can find whether a sentence is positive or neutral or negative.

i searched online found that through a [medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/positive-or-negative-spam-or-not-spam-a-simple-text-classification-problem-using-python-727efd64c238) that it can be done using NLTK library.

So, i have tried this code.

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews


def extract_features(word_list):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in word_list])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load positive and negative reviews
    positive_fileids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')
    negative_fileids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')

    features_positive = [(extract_features(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])),
                          'Positive') for f in positive_fileids]
    features_negative = [(extract_features(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])),
                          'Negative') for f in negative_fileids]

    # Split the data into train and test (80/20)
    threshold_factor = 0.8
    threshold_positive = int(threshold_factor * len(features_positive))
    threshold_negative = int(threshold_factor * len(features_negative))

    features_train = features_positive[:threshold_positive] + features_negative[:threshold_negative]
    features_test = features_positive[threshold_positive:] + features_negative[threshold_negative:]
    print("\nNumber of training datapoints:", len(features_train))
    print("Number of test datapoints:", len(features_test))

    # Train a Naive Bayes classifier
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(features_train)
    print("\nAccuracy of the classifier:", nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, features_test))

    print("\nTop 10 most informative words:")
    for item in classifier.most_informative_features()[:10]:
        print(item[0])

    # Sample input reviews
    input_reviews = [
    "Started off as the greatest series of all time, but had the worst ending of all time.",
    "Exquisite. 'Big Little Lies' takes us to an incredible journey with its emotional and intriguing storyline.",
    "I love Brooklyn 99 so much. It has the best crew ever!!",
    "The Big Bang Theory and to me it's one of the best written sitcoms currently on network TV.",
    "'Friends' is simply the best series ever aired. The acting is amazing.",
    "SUITS is smart, sassy, clever, sophisticated, timely and immensely entertaining!",
    "Cumberbatch is a fantastic choice for Sherlock Holmes-he is physically right (he fits the traditional reading of the character) and he is a damn good actor",
    "What sounds like a typical agent hunting serial killer, surprises with great characters, surprising turning points and amazing cast."
    "This is one of the most magical things I have ever had the fortune of viewing.",
    "I don't recommend watching this at all!"
    ]

    print("\nPredictions:")
    for review in input_reviews:
        print("\nReview:", review)
        probdist = classifier.prob_classify(extract_features(review.split()))
        pred_sentiment = probdist.max()
        print("Predicted sentiment:", pred_sentiment)
        print("Probability:", round(probdist.prob(pred_sentiment), 2))
```

and here is the output i got

```
Number of training datapoints: 1600
Number of test datapoints: 400

Accuracy of the classifier: 0.735

Top 10 most informative words:
outstanding
insulting
vulnerable
ludicrous
uninvolving
avoids
astounding
fascination
affecting
seagal

Predictions:

Review: Started off as the greatest series of all time, but had the worst ending of all time.
Predicted sentiment: Negative
Probability: 0.64

Review: Exquisite. 'Big Little Lies' takes us to an incredible journey with its emotional and intriguing storyline.
Predicted sentiment: Positive
Probability: 0.89

Review: I love Brooklyn 99 so much. It has the best crew ever!!
Predicted sentiment: Negative
Probability: 0.51

Review: The Big Bang Theory and to me it's one of the best written sitcoms currently on network TV.
Predicted sentiment: Positive
Probability: 0.62

Review: 'Friends' is simply the best series ever aired. The acting is amazing.
Predicted sentiment: Positive
Probability: 0.55

Review: SUITS is smart, sassy, clever, sophisticated, timely and immensely entertaining!
Predicted sentiment: Positive
Probability: 0.82

Review: Cumberbatch is a fantastic choice for Sherlock Holmes-he is physically right (he fits the traditional reading of the character) and he is a damn good actor
Predicted sentiment: Positive
Probability: 1.0

Review: What sounds like a typical agent hunting serial killer, surprises with great characters, surprising turning points and amazing cast.This is one of the most magical things I have ever had the fortune of viewing.
Predicted sentiment: Positive
Probability: 0.95

Review: I don't recommend watching this at all!
Predicted sentiment: Negative
Probability: 0.53

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The issue I'm facing is that the dataset is very limited and hence the output accuracy is very low. Is there any better library or resource or anything else to check whether a statement is positive, neutral or negative?

More specifically, I want to apply it on general day-to-day talk

Comment: There are a lot of sentiment analysis datasets present online which you can use. Otherwise you can scrape comments from a website or using the twitter API.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about twitter API... figuring out it... thanks

Comment: hi, tried the VADER sentiment analysis... and got better result than the above code... so, just wanted to ask, which one is batter textblob or VADER?

Comment: For a tiny dataset with only 2000 records, it's not really about which package or classifier is better. You can see several of the "Top 10 most informative words" your classifier learned don't even carry sentiment: 'seagal' is merely the actor/director's name, and 'avoids', 'fascination', 'insulting' are borderline meaningless.

Comment: Tagged: [tag:sentiment-analysis]

Comment: (Ok, 'seagal' conveys sentiment in the 2010s inasmuch as these days, only diehard (Steven) Seagal fans watch his films, they're all the same genre, and said fans are predisposed to liking them. But as Kerem says, if you use bag-of-words that classifier won't tell you anything about whether those fans like Bruce Willis, Vin Diesel etc.).

Comment: *"More specifically, I want to apply it on general day-to-day talk"* Then don't use a small film-review dataset. Use something more general and larger, e.g. social-media.

Comment: this movie review was just for example purpose and yes few bag of words wont be enough... so, learning more about VADER and textblob as of now

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Customer Reviews dataset is a huge dataset consisting of 130+ million customer reviews. You can use it for sentiment analysis by matching reviews and ratings. That much of data is also very suitable for super fancy data-hungry deep learning methods.

(https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-reviews-pds/readme.html)

If you are particularly search for movie reviews, Large Movie Review Dataset is also a choice which consists of 50K+ IMDB reviews. 
(http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/)

I recommend to enchance your model using word embeddings instead of one-hot encoded bag of words.

Comment: and according to you, which sentiment analysis is good to start with textblob, VADER or anything else ?

Comment: It depends on your needs and where you use this in the real-world. VADER uses a rule-based approach which may outperform learning-based methods when there is lack of data for your domain. On the other hand Textblob uses pretrained (in movie reviews) NaiveBayes Classifier. It can work better than your code if it was trained with a bigger dataset. So best way is to trying different methods to achieve best results in terms of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some available corpora:

English:

1) Multidomain sentiment analysis dataset: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~mdredze/datasets/sentiment/

2) IMDB reviews: http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/

3) Stanford Sentiment Treebank: http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

4) Sentiment140: http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students/

5) Twitter US Airline Sentiment: https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-airline-sentiment

and etc here: [50 free Machine Learning datasets: Sentiment Analysis](https://blog.cambridgespark.com/50-free-machine-learning-datasets-sentiment-analysis-b9388f79c124) and here: [nlpprogress](http://nlpprogress.com/english/sentiment_analysis.html).

Chinese:

7) THUCNews: http://thuctc.thunlp.org/

8) TouTiao: https://github.com/fate233/toutiao-text-classfication-dataset

9) SogouCA: https://www.sogou.com/labs/resource/ca.php

10) SogouCS: https://www.sogou.com/labs/resource/cs.php

and etc [here](https://blog.csdn.net/alip39/article/details/95891321).

Once your dataset is big enough you can use a discriminative model because for a small dataset a generative model can prevent overfitting while for a big dataset a discriminative model can capture dependencies that generative models cannot(as detailed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12456/103153)).

[It's](https://youtu.be/7rp2c7JVymE) said that a tree structure would be better to model the sentiment with not too much data, then I think we can consider [the tree-structured LSTM](https://github.com/sapruash/RecursiveNN) here.